# Unable to locate textfield in appium iOS using xpath and name or id is not available

Tags: ios, appium, robotframework

Unable to locate textfield in appium iOS using xpath and name or id is not available.

These are the attributes:

```
[
  { "key": "elementId", "value": "1F000000-0000-0000-9F02-000000000000", "name": "elementId" },
  { "key": "type", "value": "XCUIElementTypeTextField", "name": "type" },
  { "key": "value", "value": "12B4 - 78JT - 465K - XY44", "name": "value" },
  { "key": "label", "value": "", "name": "label" },
  { "key": "enabled", "value": "true", "name": "enabled" },
  { "key": "visible", "value": "true", "name": "visible" },
  { "key": "x", "value": "30", "name": "x" },
  { "key": "y", "value": "348", "name": "y" },
  { "key": "width", "value": "315", "name": "width" },
  { "key": "height", "value": "22", "name": "height" },
  { "key": "index", "value": "3", "name": "index" }
]
```

And the xpath as shown in Appium Inspector is:

```
//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name="Access"]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeScrollView/XCUIElementTypeOther[1]/XCUIElementTypeTextField
```

None is helping.

I am using robot framework, appium, iOS 14.4